# Authenticate Jenkins on GitHub through SSH

Tags: android, jenkins, github

I am trying to setup an android project on jenkins. It will help me genrate the apk.
My source code is on GitHub.
According to the mechanism given in following link, jenkins will use an user account's SSH key to authenticate on GitHub.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jenkins-and-git-integration-using-ssh-key/

My concern is, if access right is revoked for that particular user account, then my jenkins job will start failing.

So instead of using SSH key of a particular user account, is there any mechanism where some sort of service account can be used?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any mechanism where some sort of service account can be used?

If this is for accessing a public repository, you would not need any account: a clone (which is all that Jenkins usually needs) does not require authentication.

If this is for a private repository, then "an access right is revoked for that particular user account" would affect said account anyway.

As [illustrated by this thread](https://github.community/t/can-i-give-read-only-access-to-a-private-repo-from-a-developer-account/441/95), there is no "read access for private repository".

Comment: thanks @VonC. But I am still clueless. Mine is private repository. So, I don't want to use SSH of a user account.